# Getting a single MYSQL result where the field is an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

Wordpress database, bit stuck on this one.

I'm using the following to get the ID of the current user.

```
 $user_ID = get_current_user_id();
```

This returns something like this :

```
 15
```

Now I try to find the matching value of **$user_ID** in the field **show_user_list** The data in this field is stored in an array.

Which looks something like this :

```
 a:2:{i:0;s:2:"29";i:1;s:2:"15";}
```

This is the query i'm running (along with a set of conditions) :

```
global $wpdb; $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE show_user_list IN (' . implode(',', $user_ID) . ' AND post_type = 'show' AND post_status = 'publish'" );
```

And then I'm trying to echo the value of the matching **post_id** with this :

```
 foreach ( $result as $unique ) {
 echo $unique->post_id;
 }
```

But it's not returning anything. I know I must be making a mistake while dealing with the array but I don't know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have stored a serialized array in the show_user_list field, so it will be a hustle to search for values into using a db query.

In the model you described, you have to select all the rows from wp_postmeta that match "post_type = 'show' AND post_status = 'publish'", then manually filter results that do not have the user id in the unserialized show_user_list field.

You might try something like : 
`in_array($user_ID, unserialize($row->show_user_list))`

Also, I noticed multiple errors in your query: string not properly concatenated with PHP code and the right parenthesis of the IN clause not closed.

Regards,
same

**EDIT**

Here is how I would solve your problem providing info you have given :

```
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id, show_user_list FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_type = 'show' AND post_status = 'publish'");
$user_post_ids = array();
foreach ($results as $post) {
    if (in_array($user_ID, unserialize($post->show_user_list))) {
        $user_post_ids[] = $post->post_id;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks for your help Same. I really have no idea how to implement what you have suggested though. Any pointers you could offer would be great.